Convert an Array to Object in Symfony Form (with Easyadmin 4)
I use Symfony 7 with Easyadmin 4.
For technical reasons, I create a select field from existing ProjectPositions in my form using Ajax. When submitting the form it tries to write the array with the selected option into a ProjectPosition-field, expecting an object, which gives an error.
Question: When submitting the form, can I convert the array to an Object to avoid the error?
Custom ProjectPositionsField in Form/Field/ProjectPositionsField.php:
public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null)
{
    return (new self())
        ->setProperty($propertyName) // (= projectPosition)
        ->setLabel('')
        ->setFormType(ProjectPositionsType::class)
        ->setDefaultColumns('col-md-4 col-xxl-3')
        ->setFormTypeOptions([
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'activity_projectPositions',
                'name' => 'Activity[projectPosition]',
            ]
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'mapped' => false, 
    ]);
}

Custom ProjectPositionsType in Form/Field/ProjectPositionsType.php:
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add('projectPosition', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => ProjectPosition::class,
        'choice_label' => 'description', 
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Select a position',
        'choices' => [],
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => null,
    ]);
}

Error:
Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\ProjectPosition", "array" given at property path "projectPosition".

Load options dynamic:
success: function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(position) {
                    projectPositionDropdown.append('<option value="' + position.id + '">' + position.task + '</option>');
                });
                $("#Activity_projectPosition").show();
            },


It looks like you have a multiple EntityType form but your form only allows one element (multiple is false). Can you please provide a dump of the request when posting ?

Dump: projectPosition is an array with the ID of the position as the value. So i know why i get this error message, but how can i pass the object instead?
